# The "absolute" version of the Axiom Schema of Replacement in ZFC

Tags: set-theory, independence-results

The well-known [Axiom Schema of Replacement in ZFC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_replacement) says that for any formula $\varphi$ of the Set Theory with free variables among $w_1,\dots,w_n,A,x,y$ the following holds:

$$\forall w_1,\dots,w_n\;\forall A ([\forall x\in A\;\exists !y\;(\phi(x,y,w_1,\dots,w_n,A)]\Rightarrow \exists B\;[\forall x\in A\;\exists y\in B\;\;\varphi(x,y,w_1,\dots,w_n,A)]),$$
where $B$ is not free for $\varphi$.

I am interested in the meaning of the quantifier $\exists !$ in the above formula.

To illustrate the problem, let us consider the formula $\varphi$ with two free variables $x,y$: $$\mbox{($y$ is a cardinal) $\wedge$ $(|x|\le |y|<|\mathcal P(x)|)$}.$$ This formula defines a function assigning to each set $x$ its cardinal $y=|x|$ if and only if GCH (the Generalized Continuum Hypothesis) holds. So, for this formula the quantifier $\exists !$ holds if and only if GCH is true. This example shows that there are at least two meanings of the Axiom Schema of Replacement: the standard one and the absolute, in which we take into account only the formulas which determine a function in any model.

> **Question.** Does this "absolute" version of the Axiom Schema of Replacement lead to an essentially different Set Theory comparing to the standard ZFC?

Comment: The "absolute" version is what one might call the "replacement rule": from a deduction of $\Gamma \vdash \forall x \in A\,\exists! y\,\ldots$ infer that $\Gamma \vdash \exists B\,\forall x \in A\,\exists y \in B\,\ldots$. A common motto in proof theory is that "rules are weaker than axioms". That said, I never considered this particular instance.

Comment: There are two versions of this that I can see: the theory consisting of $\mathsf{ZC}$ + replacement for all $\varphi$ that $\mathsf{ZFC}$ prove define functions, or the smallest extension $\Gamma$ of $\mathsf{ZC}$ by replacement instances such that whenever $\Gamma$ proves that $\varphi$ defines a function we have the replacement instance for $\varphi$ in $\Gamma$. (This ignores parameters, but meh.) Which are you asking about?

Comment: @NoahSchweber Probably the second option is more natural, but also more complicated to formulate.

Comment: I don't think the unique existential quantifier holds only if GCH is true, without assuming anything about whether there are cardinals between $\vert x\vert$ and $\vert\mathcal P(x)\vert$ we may let $y$ be the cardinal $\vert x\vert$ (using the von Neumann cardinal assignment) and we have $\varphi(x,y)$.

Comment: @C7X By Lindenbaum-Tarski-Sierpinski Theorem (announced by Lindenbaum and Tarski in 1926 and proved by Sierpinski in 1947), GCH implies AC, so for any set x a cardinal y with |x|=|y| indeed exists under GCH.

Comment: @TarasBanakh Apologies, you are correct. In particular I missed the unique existential quantification apparent in "this formula defines a function."

Comment: These are equivalent. Replacement for a formula $\phi(x,y,\dots)$ follows from "absolute replacement" for the formula $\forall y'\,(\phi(x,y',\dots)\leftrightarrow y'=y)\lor(y=\varnothing\land\neg\exists!y'\,\phi(x,y',\dots))$ (i.e., "if there is a unique element satisfying $\phi$, then $y$ is this element, otherwise $y$ is a canonical fixed element").

Comment: @FrançoisG.Dorais The correct motto is that rules are equivalent to axioms unless you restrict the complexity of the formulas that go into them. For example, the unrestricted induction rule is equivalent to the induction axiom, and similarly for collection and other rules, such as the one here. However, the induction rule for, say, $\Sigma_1$-formulas is strictly weaker than the $\Sigma_1$-induction axiom.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Thank you for the comment, but if those two replacements are equivalent, then why the image of $x$ under such an absolute $\phi$ will depend on the model: it will be either empty or the image of $x$ under the function determined by $\phi$ if the quantifier $\exists !$ holds in the model. Can it happen that "absolute" replacement will produce a smaller class of (say constructive) sets comparing to the standard replacing axiom?

Comment: I don’t quite understand the issue. Irrespective of which of the two versions of replacement you consider, the same formula yields different results in different models, or rather, if you take two arbitrary models of set theory, there is not even any sensible way of stating that an element of one model is “the same” as an element of the other model. Even if you consider a transitive submodel of another model with the same ordinals, where such comparison makes sense, your definition of “absolute replacement” does not actually imply that the definition of the function is absolute in this sense.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek In the same model of ZFC, we can compare the submodels of constructible sets for two axiom systems ZFC and ZC+"absolute" F. Since the latter has smaller number of axioms, the constructible universe of the "absolute" ZFC can be smaller than the standard constructible universe $L$. Or it is the same?

Comment: The definition of the constructible universe is not parametrized by any axioms, so I don’t understand what you mean by “constructible sets for two axiom systems”.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek By the constructible universe for a given system of axioms I understand the smallest class of sets (maybe containing all ordinals) for which all the axioms hold. Removing some axioms from the list makes the constructible universe is smaler.

Comment: Why should such a smallest class exist for general axiom systems? But anyway, since ZFC and ZC + absolute F are equivalent, they are valid in exactly the same classes of sets. So under this definition they have the same constructible universe.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Ok. Thank you for the explanation. Asking this question I wanted to turn the attention that the Fraenkel's Replacement Axiom in ZFC is not as simple as it may seem, in contrast to the corresponding axiom of NBG.